# How to use layout vertical?

Tags: appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app using Appcelerator.
In this app I got a main wrapper view and some subviews. I need them to be placed under each other using the layout vertical property but they all stack in a pile (not on separate "rows").

What is wrong with the code below?

```
// Create the padding view

            container = Ti.UI.createView({ 

                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                width: 320,
                height: 460,
                backgroundColor: '#000'

            });

            // Create the padding view

            wrapper = Ti.UI.createView({ 

                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                width: 320,
                height: 'auto',
                layout: 'vertical'

            });

            // Create the padding view

            label = Ti.UI.createLabel({ 

                text: e.label,
                color: e.color,
                font:{fontSize:36,fontWeight: 'normal'},
                top: 10,
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto'

            });

            // Create the padding view

            perks_label = Ti.UI.createLabel({ 

                text: 'Lorem Ipsum is',
                color: '#fff',
                font:{fontSize:26,fontWeight: 'normal'},
                top: 10,
                left: 10,
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto'

            });

            // Create the padding view

            perks_data = Ti.UI.createLabel({ 

                text: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer',
                color: '#fff',
                font:{fontSize:12,fontWeight: 'normal'},
                top: 10,
                left: 10,
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto'

            });

            // Add label to wrapper

            wrapper.add(label);

            // Add label to wrapper

            wrapper.add(perks_label);

            // Add label to wrapper

            wrapper.add(perks_data);

            // Add wrapper to container

            container.add(wrapper);

            // Return the row

            return container;
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code, and it works as you intend on Android. Have you tried it using specific height values for the labels? If Titanium's having trouble figuring out how tall the labels are that would affect the automatic positioning.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the top and left of perks_label and perks_data should be different.  Try setting the perks_data to top:50.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this wall before. Have you set the layout for the current window to 'vertical'? So, from the window that you add the container to, set its layout to vertical:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
win.layout = 'vertical';
```